# Text Input error / validation and restore previous correct value in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, validation, textbox

I have text input boxes. There is validation for each of the boxes using numberValidator.
Now, the thing is that am using alert box to show if any error occurs.

Flowchart ::

1> Insert value in textBox.
2> NumberValidator validates the input on "trigger=change".
3> If error, alert message is displayed. The user clicks OK to go back to form.
4> Focus set back to the TextBox.
5> But, alert box makes the text input value blank / null. i.e. Both the previous error value entered by user and the default correct value will not be displayed now.

Goal : Display the most recent correct value that was entered in the text box. Not the default of any other, but the most recent correct value entered by the user.

can anyone help ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete answer. I used the "enter" event of the text box to do validation since the "change" event fires after only a single character is entered

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
                layout="absolute">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert

            // set last correct value to a default
            private var lastCorrectValue:String="411"

            function handleInvalid(event:Event)
            {
                Alert.show("invalid");
                textInput.text=lastCorrectValue
            }

            function handleValid()
            {
                Alert.show('Validation Succeeded!')
                lastCorrectValue=textInput.text
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:TextInput id="textInput"
                  text="{lastCorrectValue}"/>
    <!-- Use the enter event of the text box to do validation. The change event fires after a single character-->
    <mx:NumberValidator source="{textInput}"
                        property="text"
                        integerError="Enter Integer value"
                        domain="int"
                        trigger="{textInput}"
                        triggerEvent="enter"
                        invalid="handleInvalid(event)"
                        valid="handleValid();"/>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: The triggerEvent="enter" does not work. Infact, the change event works. No validation takes place when trigger=enter is mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store the most recent correct answer in a variable and have the click/close handler of the alert replace the value with the stored var.

here is an example of listening for alert event:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- controls\alert\AlertEvent.mxml -->
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.CloseEvent;

            private var lastKnownCorrectAnswer:String = "Some Answer";

            private function alertListener(eventObj:CloseEvent):void {
                // Check to see if the OK button was pressed.
                if (eventObj.detail==Alert.OK) {
                    myText.text = lastKnownCorrectAnswer; 
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:TextInput id="myAnswer" 
        width="150" 
        text="" />
    <mx:Button id="myButton" 
        label="Copy Text" 
        click='Alert.show("Copy Text?", "Alert",
            Alert.OK | Alert.CANCEL, this,
            alertListener, null, Alert.OK);'/>
</mx:Application>
```

You will need to add your validation logic in there, but you get the idea. The above is from the [Alert docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/201/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Book_Parts&file=controls_059_22.html).

Comment: Ok...I get the idea....But, can you elaborate on how I can keep track of lastKnownCorrectAnswer ??

Comment: when a user enters a correct answer you would place it in that variable. When you initialize the component, you would set that variable to the default (assuming it is a correct answer). Without seeing your specific component, it would be difficult to give a more precise answer. If you want to edit and provide code I will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Fire a event on the Text Input FocusIn() and store whatever text value in a variable. (That would be your last correct answer). Reset the inputbox text to this value after validation... Hope I made sense :)